# What is the name for the operation of swapping the two components of a complex number (rectangular form)?

Tags: complex-numbers, terminology

I wonder if there is a name for the operation of swapping the real and imaginary part of a complex number.

Comment: "Reflection in the diagonal". If you mean is there a function specifically for doing this, not really, $z \mapsto i\cdot \overline{z}$ is slim enough.

Comment: Do you mean $3+2i=>2+3i$?

Comment: @JasonChen: Yes.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks.  Maybe you want to put it as an answer?